# Image not uploaded from android to server

Tags: php, android

I am new to android , trying to upload image from android to server.
Below is code. Always getting fail message from php.

imageupload.php

```
$type1 = $_REQUEST['type']  ;
    $now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    if($type1 == "Exhibition"){
        $type = 1;
    }
    if($type1 == "Wedding"){
        $type = 2;
    }
    if($type1 == "Culture"){
        $type = 3;
    }
    if($type1 == "Corporate"){
        $type = 4;
    }
    if($type1 == "Sports"){
        $type = 5;
    }
    if($type1 == "Others"){
        $type = 6;
    }

        echo $img_file=$_FILES['image_file']['name'];
        $img_ext=substr($img_file,-4);
        $img_folder="include/img/";
        $img_path=$img_folder.rand(10000,990000).$img_ext;
        $img_type=pathinfo($img_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if((move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_file"]["tmp_name"],$img_path)))
            {
                $jsonarray = array('result'=>'success','msg'=>'Event Added Successfully');      
                }else{
                    $jsonarray = array('result'=>'fail','msg'=>'Something went wrong');
                    echo $myJSON = json_encode($jsonarray);
                }
            }
        else
        {
            $jsonarray = array('result'=>'fail','msg'=>'Failed To Add Event');
            echo $myJSON = json_encode($jsonarray);
        }
```

UpcomingEvents.java

```
public class UpcomingEvents extends AppCompatActivity  {
Spinner spinner;
String type;
String[] SPINNERVALUES = {"Exhibition","Wedding","Culture","Corporate","Sports","Others"};
ImageView image;
Button choose, upload;
int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
String URL ="http://10.0.2.2/productioneventapi/imageupload.php";
Bitmap bitmap;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_upcoming_events);

  spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpcomingEvents.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SPINNERVALUES);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
      type = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
  });
  image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  choose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageupload);
  upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addevent);
  choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setType("image/*");
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
  });
  upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UpcomingEvents.this);
      progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading, please wait...");
      progressDialog.show();

      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
      byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
      final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

      StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            String code = jsonObject.getString("msg");
            if (code.equals("success")) {
              Toast.makeText(UpcomingEvents.this,jsonObject.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
              Toast.makeText(UpcomingEvents.this,jsonObject.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage()+"] "+s);
          }
        }
      },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
          Toast.makeText(UpcomingEvents.this, "Some error occurred -> "+volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
        }
      }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
          Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
          parameters.put("image_file", imageString);
          parameters.put("type",type);
          return parameters;
        }
      };

      RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UpcomingEvents.this);
      rQueue.add(request);
    }
  });
}

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
      Uri filePath = data.getData();

      try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

}
In android image is encoded to base64, how to decode that in php?
I tried using 
**$imageData = base64_decode($_REQUEST['image_file']);
    $img_file=$imageData;**
this also not working, 
Whether my way is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'msg'=>'Something went wrong');` That is not very informative. You should change that script so it tells the real reason.

Comment: Ok. But then also it is giving same message "Failed To Add Event"

Comment: That is also a very bad error message. As it does tell nothing about the reason.

Comment: `$img_file=$imageData;` We wonder what you have in mind with that statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters.put("image_file", imageString);
```

If you do that then you send the file base64 encoded in a parameter.

Your php script expects that you send a file. If you keep the Volley code then you can get the base64 string with

```
$imageString = $_REQUEST['image_file'];
```

Your `move_uploaded_file()` cannot be used now.

But `$imageData = base64_decode($_REQUEST['image_file']);` should work. You only have to save the data to file yet yourself.

Comment: I used   'file_put_contents("include/img/".$img_path,$imageData);'  then also not working, is it correct?

Comment: Well that should do it if that path is correct.What is the return value?  What are the error(s) you get? Does that directory exist? You could checkexistence before you try to put something in it. Please tell the value of `"include/img/".$img_path`.If it fails then let the php script echo this path. Be informative.